# How to use c++20 <ranges> in xcode 13?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++20

I'm trying to use c++20 library  in Xcode 13.1

```cpp
#include <ranges>
```

I have set `Apple Clang - Languages - C++` to `-std=c++20` and compiler default, but it still throws `'ranges' file not found`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this feature list

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20

Clang 13 claims "Partial" support, while Apple Clang seems to have none.

(Don't be confused by version numbers. Apple 13.1 doesn't have to be later than LLVM 13.0).

Comment: Thanks! I thought apple clang and clang is the same thing. I tried to install clang 13 and it just throws a “wchar.h” not found error. I tried looking it up, most solutions just mentions doing a fresh xcode-select —install, which doesn’t really help in this case :(

Comment: Apple Clang and LLVM Clang are based on the same code base, but they are released at different times (like when a new OS release happens) and have a separate system for version numbers.

Comment: @JohnsonZhou Releases: https://xcodereleases.com/ Toolchain versions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Toolchain_versions Apple Clang is not LLVM and versions don't match, neither features even if a Apple Clang version uses a particular LLVM version. For example Apple Clang 13 does not support all the features supported by LLVM 13. Apple was supposed to start using mainstream LLVM but I guess that didn't happed and maybe won't happen any time soon if ever.